# Get maximum value containing row using groupby function in laravel

Tags: laravel, group-by, max

I need help in getting the max `data_date` of a table that is grouped by `report_type_id` in laravel.So in order to get this i wrote my query like this

```
$latest_reports =  Filelist::
whereRaw('data_date in (select max(data_date) from filelists  GROUP BY (report_type_id))')
->where('access_id','=',$retailer_supplier_id->id)
->get();
```

Here is my table please have a look

```
id    access_id   filename      report_type_id    data_date

1       16        filename1            6         2021-02-01

2       16        filename2            6         2021-01-01

3       16        filename3            6         2021-03-01

4       16        filename4            6         2021-04-01

5       16        filename5            7         2021-03-01

6       16        filename6            7         2021-05-01
```

Am getting result like this

```
id    access_id   filename      report_type_id    data_date

1       16        filename1            6         2021-02-01

3       16        filename3            6         2021-03-01

4       16        filename1            6         2021-04-01
```

I want to get result like this

```
id    access_id   filename      report_type_id    data_date

4       16        filename4            6         2021-04-01

6       16        filename6            7         2021-05-01
```

Comment: why dont you use order by desc and then group it by report id

Comment: @Rafee i had done that `$latest_reports = Filelist::
                      select('report_type_id',DB::raw('filename,max(data_date) as latest_date'))
                     ->where('access_id','=',$retailer_supplier_id->id)
                     ->groupBy('report_type_id')
                     ->orderBy('data_date','desc') 
                     ->get();` but its not working

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get one earler  recod regarding date

Try this

```
$latest_report= Fielist::where('access_id','=',$retailer_supplier_id- 
>id)->latest('data_date')groupby('report_type_id')->first();
```

if you want to get the earler 2 regads try this

```
 $latest_reports= Fielist::where('access_id','=',$retailer_supplier_id- 
>id)->groupby('report_type_id')
->order_by('datetime', 'desc')
->limit(2)->get();
```

Comment: Can't use first there because multiple results will be coming based on `access_id` and `report_type_id`

Comment: try this and it will get you the recods which are note repeaded

Comment: which produce same result